# How to rewrite "I passed a good week with you."

Tags: grammar, verbs

I have a problem to rewrite the sentence, "I passed a good week with you." 
I thought of "I spent a good week with you." or "I had a good week with you."
The direction says not to change the wording or meaning of the original sentence so much.
Are my sentences grammatically okay? Does it sound naturally to native people?
If there is a better way to say so, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: “I had a nice week with you” or “I’ve had a nice week with you” (if you’re just saying goodbye at the end of the week) is very natural. ‘Spent’ is fine, too, though slightly less natural combined with ‘you’. “I spent a very nice week with him in New York” is very natural, though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should have been posted on [ell.se] instead of here.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework question where you need to rewrite various sentences that are phrased a bit ungainly or unnaturally.

"Passing a good week" certainly qualifies as both ungainly and unnatural. Even though pastimes are things we do to pass the time away, saying "I passed a good week with you" sounds too much like a bad biological experience that eventually, ummm, passed.

Your first alternative, using "spent" rather than "passed" is perfectly valid. In this context, "spend" is a synonym for "pass." Your second alternative is also valid. I like the first alternative better than the second, but that's just personal preference.

There is a potential problem with your rewrite. You are interpreting "good week" as a week during which a number of nice events occurred. A very different interpretation of "I passed a good week with you" is possible. Idiomatically, "passing time" has an air of indolence to it. When we "pass the time away" we might as well be just twiddling our thumbs. With this interpretation, that good week was something wasted rather than something to be remembered fondly. A rewrite that captures this sense of passage of time is

> I wasted a good week with you!

The above sentence has a very different meaning than "I spent/had a good week with you".

Answer (score 0):

I think your meaning is entirely clear. Your construction is similar to "We passed time by playing cards". I can see no need to alter it.

I spent a good week, or I had a good week, or I enjoyed a good week, would all be equally clear but are no better than "passed".

Comment: I disagree with this answer. When used transitively, you can "pass" lots of things: A kidney stone, a ball, a car, counterfeit money. You cannot pass a week. A week can pass by but that usage is intransitive. The sentence to be reworded uses "pass" as a transitive verb with "a good week" as the subject. That is invalid.